# How to solve apt-utils : depends on: apt (= 1.6.8) but 1.6.10 is installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

These are my (german) messages translated to English via Google Translate:

```
Package lists are read ... Done
Dependency tree is set up.
Status information is read .... Done
Try "apt --fix-broken install" to correct this.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  apt-utils: Depends on: apt (= 1.6.8) but 1.6.10 is installed
E: Unfulfilled dependencies. Try apt -fix-broken install without specifying a package (or specify a solution).
```

When I try:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

I get the error message:

> apt
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Output from: sudo apt update && apt-cache policy apt-utils

> Installed:           1.6.8   Installationcandidate: 1.6.10
>   Versiontable:
>        1.6.10 500
>           500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages  *** 1.6.8 100
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>        1.6.6ubuntu0.1 500
>           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
>        1.6.1 500
>           500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: LC=C does not work. For sudo apt install -f -> dpkg messages an error: inconsistency of packages

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && apt-cache policy apt-utils` please.  Add the output to your question as an edit.